# Retrieve sequelize rows through a many-to-many relationship table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models `Company` and `Contractor` linked through a `CompanyContractor` relational table.

**company.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    slug: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: DataTypes.STRING(200),
  }, {});

  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.belongsToMany(models.Contractor, { through: 'CompanyContractor', as: 'contractors',foreignKey: 'companyId' });
  };

  return Company;
};
```

**contractor.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Contractor = sequelize.define('Contractor', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {});
  Contractor.associate = function(models) {
    Contractor.belongsToMany(models.Company, { through: 'CompanyContractor', as: 'contractors' });
  };
  return Contractor;
};
```

**companyContractor.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CompanyContractor = sequelize.define('CompanyContractor', {
    companyId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    contractorId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });

  return CompanyContractor;
};
```

Is there a way to `Contractor.findAll()` through `companyId`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Contractor.findAll({
include: [{
   model: Company,
   through: {
        attributes: ['companyId']
      }
   }]
});
```

[From the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Comment: Sorry for not explaining adequately.  I wanted to retrieve a list of Contractors by supplying a companyId value.  I don't need any Company data.  The only way I figured out was to query the association table directly with companyId and then use results as Op.in Contractors.map(...).  But would like something a bit more elegant from the orm.